# How to improve these codes about dividing students groups randomly in Python

Tags: python

I'm using Python and want to improve these codes that write by myself about dividing groups randomly. I hope to have an effective coding style to generate the grouping randomly, each team has 5 students and need be randomly distributed one case from 10 overall

I have tried to use 2 loops and dictionary to add the key as a case and the value as a student and try to figure out the format to group 5 students and show what case they have in the while loop section

```
#sample data
students_list =['s1','s2','s3','s4','s5','s6','s7','s8','s9','s10']
cases_list =['case1','case2','case3','case4','case5','case6','case7','case8','case9','case10']

import random

match_dict = {}
count = 0
random.shuffle(cases_list)

if len(students_list) <= len(cases_list) and len(students_list) > 0:
    for case in cases_list:
        for student in students_list:
            if case not in match_dict.keys():
                match_dict[case] = student
                students_list.remove(student)     
else:
    raise ValueError("Not enough case!")

print("\n")

my_case = list(match_dict.keys())
my_student = list(match_dict.values())
cases = []
group = int(len(my_student)/5)


while count < len(my_student):
    for num in range(0,group):
        print("Group {my_group}".format(my_group = num +1))

        for i in range(count,count+5):
            print("Studnet ID: ",my_student[i+0])
            cases.append(my_case[i+0])
        print("Assigned cases are ",cases)
        count = count + 5
        cases = []

        print("\n -----Next group----- \n")
```

Expected results

```
Group 1
Studnet ID:  s1
Studnet ID:  s4
Studnet ID:  s7
Studnet ID:  s8
Studnet ID:  s10
Assigned cases are  n
```

-----Next group-----

Comment: To clarify: can multiple students from different groups be assigned the same case? Can multiple students from the same group be assigned the same case? Can a student be in multiple groups?

Comment: 1. Multiple students from different groups cannot be assigned the same case. I hope mutiple students will happen once from each group. 2.No, it cannot. I hope multiple students from the same group can be assigned different cases. 3. A student cannot be in multiple groups. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

students_list = [
    's1','s2','s3','s4','s5',
    's6','s7','s8','s9','s10'
    ]

cases_list = [
    'case1','case2','case3','case4','case5',
    'case6','case7','case8','case9','case10'
    ]

random.shuffle(students_list)
random.shuffle(cases_list)

groups = [students_list[i:i + 5] for i in range(0, len(students_list), 5)]

for i, g in enumerate(groups):
    print("Group", i + 1)

    for s in g:
        print("Student ID", s)

    print("Cases: ", end = "")

    for j in range(i * 5, (i * 5) + 5):
        print(cases_list[j], end = ", ")

    print("\n- - - - -")
```

I don't fully understand what you are asking for, how does this compare to your expectations?